# Check a radio button with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want my radio button to be checked when I click on it. I use JQuery to do it but my input doesn't have the checked input attribute when I inspect it.

```js
var $container = $('.maincar__currency'); // cache this for better performance as you use it multiple times

$container.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
});

$(".maincar__currency label").click(function() {
  $('#' + $(this).attr('for')).prop('checked', true);
  $container.prepend($(this));
});

$(document).click(function() {
  $container.removeClass('expanded');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="maincar__currency" id="currency-drop-is">
  <label for="euro-radio-is">
    <div class="currency currency__euro">
      <img src="/assets/images/icons/euro.png" alt="Euro sign">
      <input type="radio" name="currency-is" value="euro" id="euro-radio-is" class="euro_radio_is" checked>
      <span class="default">EUR</span>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label for="dollar-radio-is">
    <div class="currency currency__dollar">
      <img src="/assets/images/icons/dollar.png" alt="Dollar sign">
      <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="dollar-radio-is" class="dollar_radio_is" value="dollar">
      <span>USD</span>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label for="gbp-radio-is">
    <div class="currency currency__pound">
      <img src="/assets/images/icons/pound-sterling.png" alt="Pound sign">
      <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="gbp-radio-is" class="gbp_radio_is" value="gbp">
      <span>GBP</span>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label for="chf-radio-is">
    <div class="currency currency__chf">
      <img src="/assets/images/icons/swiss-franc.png" alt="Swiss franc sign">
      <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="chf-radio-is" class="chf_radio_is" value="chf">
      <span>CHF</span>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Isn't the `$('#' + $(this).attr('for')).prop('checked', true);` wrong ?

Comment: `my input doesn't have the checked input attribute when I inspect it` If you mean the DOM inspector then this is expected behaviour. The `checked` attribute does not get updated in the DOM, but the `checked` *property* on the Element does. As such your code is working fine

Comment: A label should auto select the radio button when you click on it not sure why you would need JavaScript for it.

Comment: Ok, thank you Rory, I didn't know that.